# Ajax success function isn't called with require instruction

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, require

I have really weird problem with AJAX.
This is fragment of file with js code and post method which sends params to php file via AJAX:

```js
var params = $('#add').serializeArray();

$.post('code/bg/adding_c.php', params, function(ret) {
  //body of success function
}, 'json');
```

And this is fragment of php code (adding_c.php):

```html
<?php
 require "functions.php";
 
 //irrelevant operations
 
 $return = array(
  'status' => $status,
  'msg' => $msg,
  'id' => $id
 );
 
 echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Everything works when I comment or delete the line with require instruction but when it's active, success function isn't fired.

1. JS post method sends correct params.
2. Php file receives it, does proper operations and returns correct data to js script (I can see it in FireBug).
3. Success function isn't fired.

Why instruction which isn't related with AJAX, causes this problem?

Edit.

functions.php:

```html
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'dbname';
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);


function querySQL($query)
{
 global $conn;
 $result = $conn->query($query);
 return $result;
}

function cleanSQL($conn, $string)
{
 return htmlentities(fixSQL($conn, $string), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); 
}

function fixSQL($conn, $string)
{
 if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  $string = stripslashes($string);
 
 return $conn->real_escape_string($string); 
}

function fPassword($pass)
{
 $salt1 = 'salt1';
 $salt2 = 'salt2'; 
 $token = hash('ripemd128', "$salt1$pass$salt2");
 
 return $token;
}

?>
```

Edit2.

There is no errors and when I paste functions from functions.php to index.php everything works fine. I don't know what to do now. It seems that require word is a problem here. I can't add these functions to every file in which I need them.

Comment: What the content you have in the `functions.php` ?

Comment: Connection with database and functions which I use in many files. I can post its code but when I copy it to adding_c.php everything works.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an error within `functions.php`.

**EDIT:** If you haven't set `display_errors = On` in your php.ini file, use these lines in your code:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also, are you sure it is not a parsing/syntax error? If that is the case, there's a few things you will want to do:

1. Make sure you are using an IDE that checks syntax (Netbeans, for example).
2. Separate the file into two, like so:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", "1");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include 'error.php';
```

**error.php**

```
require "functions.php";

//irrelevant operations

$return = array(
    'status' => $status,
    'msg' => $msg,
    'id' => $id
);

echo json_encode($return);
```

Run this in a browser window and that should give you an idea of what you are dealing with.

Comment: There is no errors and when I paste functions from functions.php to index.php everything works fine. I don't know what to do now. It seems that require word is a problem here. I can't add these functions to every file  in which I need them. This is hilarious.